# Understanding how to turn a chunk of code that appears in main(){} into a function or functions in C

Tags: c, arrays, function

I'm working on a user-space driver which reads data off of a device by sending and receiving reports (it's a hid device).

Here is my initial code http://pastebin.com/ufbvziUR

EDIT NOTE: From the sound of the answers and comments it would seem I will need to wrap my C code inside of some Objective-C since the app that will be consuming this driver is written in Objective-C.

As of now I have just added all the code into the `main()` function and I'm able to grab data and print it out to the log window with the main purpose of logging out the buffer array. This code will be apart of a much larger app though and will need to be ran by getting called rather than just automatically running.

So I figured I would wrap all the code that appears in `main()` inside of a large function called `getData()`. I want to return an array called `char buffer[]` (a char array full of bytes) when this function get run. My initial thought to declare it would be like so since I know you cannot really return an array from a function only a pointer so I just let the caller allocate the buffer and pass it the size.

```
char *getData(int user){
    unsigned char *buffer = malloc(2800);
    // ... do all the stuff

   return buffer;
}
```

Then in main()

```
int main(){
   int user = 1;

   unsigned char *buffer = getData(user);
}
```

Is this a proper approach?

A couple of things feel wrong to me here. First is wrapping that much code into a single function and two I'm not quite sure how to break out of the function when one of my error checks `returns 1;` since this function will need to return an array. I'm still really new to C and am getting confused on how to approach this when I don't have objects or classes to work with.

Comment: `getData(user);` is useless. You need to assign what it returns to something.

Comment: @FilipeGonçalves thanks, I updated the code some more based.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
void getData(unsigned char *buffer, int user){...}
```

Defines a function that is not returning anything.

If you want to return some value - like for instance error code, you need a function returning an int.

```
int getData(unsigned char *buffer, int user){...}
```

To get out of function returning `void` differently then reaching the end of the function, you can also use `return` but then without any arguments.

As you've already noticed you aren't passing array to the function so there is no reason to return it at all. You could return the pointer if you wanted but the is no need to do so. The main function knows where the array is anyway.

It's generally considered a good habit to keep main as short as possible. You can also divide `getData` into smaller functions which would make the code more readable. You could for instance make every chunk marked by `# pragma mark - ...` a separate function. Or even better, see whether there are any parts of the program that are doing the same or similar thing. Then you can generalize this functionality into one function and use it multiple times.

Comment: I have updated my initial code idea would something like that work a little better?

Comment: Array is of type unsigned char so the function should be of this type, not just char. But apart from this detail the change you made makes a lot of sense :)

Comment: And you would probably want to hold created buffer under some variable in main, so you would need `unsigned char *buffer = getData(user);`

Comment: thanks for that one, I added it to my example as well. But how would another part of the application in another file (which is actually written in objective-C) get access to buffer which is defined in main?

Comment: You would either need to call `getData` from the other program or call the other program passing your buffer pointer to it. Here are some starting points for combining two programs into one: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C_Programming/Preprocessor#.23include
http://www.eskimo.com/~scs/cclass/notes/sx5b.html

But it seems that you can't easily build a program out of ansi c and objective c. In your case it would be probably easiest to either choose one language or pass the data via a pipe between programs in different languages.

Comment: appreciate the links, looks like I will need to try and wrap all of this inside of Objective-C and go from there.